# Test-jig for the display system

Tags: testing, production

We have a system in which is an HMI with a display. To test a system, I have to connect the  LCD and six more cables to the board. As the LCD has an FPC cable, it will take more time compared to the other connectors. The other connectors are like USB, HDMI and wire to board connectors.

For testing a system, we have an automated test software which will test all the boards in less than two minutes if all the cables are connected. In my case, I am taking more time to connect these cables and peripherals.

Can anyone suggest whether I can make any test jigs to reduce the test time?

The system has many connectors, I don't know how I have to plan for test jig. If anyone has any experience in testing of single board computers, please help.

Comment: Do you need to test every one, or can you do random picks from production batches? What failure modes are you looking for? Does the software somehow test the LCD (what happens if it isn't connected)?

Comment: @RonBeyer, We are planning to test all the boards. I have to make sure all the interface on the boards will work properly with minimal testing. To test the LCD, operator intervention is required. It is an LCD with touch. So the test software will show some random points on the LCD and the test engineer has to touch there. then only the application will comnsider the test is passed.

Comment: How do you solve your problem. Kindly shared. I'm currently trying to make a jig same concept with you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the board designer didn't think of testability, and the sole connection to a peripheral is via a fine-pitch connector, then you have a problem; either accept the inconvenience of making that connection when testing, or redesign the board to include some test points, that can be connected using bed-of-nails 'pogo' pins.